# Add More Space to Ubuntu 18.04 Dual Boot

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, windows

I have a dual boot of Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10. Currently I have only 8 GB /20GB OF space in my home  and I have 134 GB on my /dev/sda1 which I would like to use to add more space on my home. You can refer to the screenshots of my partitions below.

[MY Partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7s7RX.png)

[Disk Partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwMMB.png)

Based on what I have researched, that I have to back up my data on a hard drive then reinstall UBuntu again. Is there no other way to add more space to my home besides this?

Thank you.

Comment: You can re-size partitions so you don't need to re-install. The partitions shouldn't be in use when you do it, so it's more easily achieved using 'live' media (eg. your Ubuntu install media using the "*Try Ubuntu*").  At worst if you're MBR/`grub` you may need to re-install `grub`, but you maybe using UEFI... With swap in the way, I'd just delete it & re-create it (this will require change due to changed UUID when re-created..)  You'll likely need more than I've provided though if you don't fully understand what I've put

Comment: Basically load UBuntu through Live USB again right ?

Comment: Yes I did mean the 'live' USB again (ie. your install media, or another system that isn't older than your 18.04 system), however I hoped someone else would have provided clearer details..  I'm very familiar with BIOS/MBR systems, but wouldn't want to advise for UEFI systems as I usually use full disk on those boxes so rarely adjust...  I'm also don't support windows 10 so am not aware of any pitfalls because of that...

Comment: So if I do it this way , don't I need to back up my data to prevent losing it ?

Comment: Of course you do backups first, you should have our normal backups anyway, but any significant change to a system causes me to create a new backup in case I make a mistake (often quicker than a restore from my normal backups), and changes to any partition table data risks damage to anything on disk should a power outage occur at the inopportune time.